# In computer science, what is a floating point?

Tags: floating-point

Sorry for the silly question, but I'm learning from the begining and I don't understand the meaning of the word "Float"?

I have an exercise where I have to square a float.

Comment: Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point, and then feel free to ask if there's anything specific about it you don't understand!

Comment: I very strongly invite you to read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Darin: That's not exactly the best intro for someone who's unaware waht floating-point is...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, and you think that the Wikipedia article is any better?

Comment: @Darin: The first 4 paragraphs of the Wikipedia article are a pretty good introduction, IMO.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, yeah, maybe you're right. Dunno. Anyway, totally off-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

it's short for  "floating point number"

which is a way to represent real numbers.